# How do I display descending data in Express js and Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to display Item data based on SumBooking data that is sorted in Descending, which is then the topmost ispopular data is made true, but I have a problem that the data is Sort Ascending

```
const category = await Category.find()
    .select("_id name")
    .limit(3)
    .populate({
      path: "itemId",
      select: "_id title sumBooking country city isPopular imageId",
      perDocumentLimit: 4,
      option: { sort: { sumBooking: -1 } },
      populate: {
        path: "imageId",
        select: "_id imageUrl",
        perDocumentLimit: 1,
      },
    });

for (let i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < category[i].itemId.length; x++) {
      const item = await Item.findOne({ _id: category[i].itemId[x]._id });

      item.isPopular = false;
      await item.save();
      if (category[i].itemId[0] === category[i].itemId[x]) {
        item.isPopular = true;
        await item.save();
      }
    }
  }
```

the results of the Codingan above will produce an image like this

https://ibb.co/zZPHXDx

what will appear at the top should be data with sumBooking 6

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working, instead, you can use aggregate, your query look like

```
const category = await Category.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "items",
    localField: "itemId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "itemId",
  },
},
{
  $unwind: "$itemId",
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    name: 1,
    "itemId._id": 1,
    "itemId.title": 1,
    "itemId.sumBooking": 1,
  },
},
{
  $sort: { "itemId.sumBooking": -1 },
},
```

]);

Comment: thanks in advance for helping, the code above has displayed the data descending, but I want the first data isPopular to be True based on the name category, like this image https://ibb.co/KxfyqsC